# Can't boot Dell after loading Ubuntu 12.04 from USB

Tags: boot

I put Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) on my new Dell I15 overwriting Windows 10, running the installer from a USB. To boot from the USB I had to change the boot order.  It all installed, but won't boot from the hard drive and I don't know how to reset the boot order.

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled secure boot in your BIOS?
Also if your Windows 10 is EFI mode you need to install Ubuntu also in EFI mode.
Any specific reasons why you are not going for LTS release - 14.04.3?
Not clear from your question "overwriting Windows 10" - are you completely getting rid of Windows 10?
In case you are done with all the stuff mentioned above and want to install Ubuntu along side Windows...then go ahead with this
Try boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

For more info, please read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Sorry te question wasn't clear - I'm replacing Win 10 altogether.

Comment: @DavidSmith. Okay in that case, please try all these steps and let us know.

Comment: I really appreciate the help - boot-repair fixed it; I had been clinging to 12.04 because didn't do well on my little old box, but I'm giving 14.04 a try.

Comment: @DavidSmith. Glad to know it worked. Please upvote this answer and accept this as an answer(tick mark)